# How to restart numbering on PHPWord with addListItem()?

Tags: listitem, phpword

I'm creating a document that will contain multiple numbered lists on a page and have created two list definitions as this:

```
  ${'references_' . $testcase} = array('listType'=>PHPWord_Style_ListItem::TYPE_NUMBER_NESTED);
  ${'procedure_' . $testcase} = array('listType'=>PHPWord_Style_ListItem::TYPE_NUMBER_NESTED);
```

They're then being called within loops to add to the lists:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
  $body->addListItem('List Item ' . $i, 0, null, ${'references_' . $testcase});
}
for ($j = 1; $j <= 10; $j++) {
  $body->addListItem('List Item ' . $j, 0, null, ${'procedure_' . $testcase});
}
```

However, the second list numbering starts at 11 - how can I have this set back to 1?

Answer (score 1):

it's an old thread and all but afaik you need to put your lists in seperate textruns to have the numbering start again

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot use `addListItem()` on a text run. The following fatal error is produced:
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Cannot add ListItem in TextRun.'`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve this myself today and I found a fork of PHPWord called [PHPWord2](https://github.com/RLovelett/PHPWord2). At the moment the code for numbering restart is only in a work branch. Read more at https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/10. Examples are included in the work branch.